# Multiple Navigation Paths to a Single Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to use the Multiple Navigation Paths to a Single Page feature from the MvcSiteMapProvider: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page

And these are the 2 different navigation path that's pointing to the same resource:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Multi Analysis" controller="Report" action="MultiAnalysis" preservedRouteParameters="id">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Analysis" controller="Report" action="Analysis" preservedRouteParameters="id,type" type="ma" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>

<mvcSiteMapNode title="Single Analysis" controller="Report" action="SingleAnalysis" preservedRouteParameters="id">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Analysis" controller="Report" action="Analysis" preservedRouteParameters="id,type" type="sa" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

But, the breadcrumb is always generated for the top one. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something you are missing. A route value and preserved route value cannot be used simultaneously for the same node. I have updated the wiki page because the example configuration was also invalid.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Multi Analysis" controller="Report" action="MultiAnalysis" preservedRouteParameters="id">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Analysis" controller="Report" action="Analysis" preservedRouteParameters="id" type="ma" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>

<mvcSiteMapNode title="Single Analysis" controller="Report" action="SingleAnalysis" preservedRouteParameters="id">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Analysis" controller="Report" action="Analysis" preservedRouteParameters="id" type="sa" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Note the lack of "type" in the preservedRouteParameters in this case.

Using preservedRouteParameters is for forcing all possible Ids to match a single node by copying the parameter from the current request. This is generally only useful for making the SiteMapPath HTML helper work alongside CRUD operations where you are using a list or table of database records as your main navigation. If you are using the Menu or SiteMap HTML helpers or you want the pages listed in the /sitemap.xml endpoint (the sitemaps XML for search engines), using preservedRouteParameters is not recommended.

I have created a working demo of this feature on my blog: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/10/mvcsitemapprovider-4-seo-features#canonical-tag

Comment: Right, but if you see the last attribute, `type="ma"`, they are actually different. I was able to resolve it using:             `MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.GetSiteMap().Clear();
            MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.GetSiteMap().BuildSiteMap();` This is my first project using this provider so I'm not familiar with how the caching works on this though.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. This doesn't really have anything to do with caching. Your configuration is invalid because you are specifying both a type and a preservedRouteParameters="type", which effectively overwrites the first type with the value from the current request. That is probably why you are getting what looks like caching problems.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have also updated the wiki, and I am looking into fixing MvcSiteMapProvider so it throws an exception when you specify the same key for both a route value and a preserved route parameter, because that could never be useful.

Comment: None of this worked for me... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for now:

`MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.GetSiteMap().Clear();
            MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.GetSiteMap().BuildSiteMap();`

I guess I'll continue using this until I figure out how the caching works on MvcSiteMapProvider

Comment: NEVER DO THIS. This effectively does an in-place rebuild of your sitemap with the cache timer still ticking. The sitemap building code is not thread safe. If multiple users call this at the same time you could end up with a partial sitemap or a sitemap with lots of duplicate nodes. BuildSiteMap() is for internal use, not to be called by end users.